# PHP array global como tabela temporaria

Tags: php, array, variáveis-globais

Estou no meio de um problema, eu gostaria de usar um `array` como uma **tabela** **temporária**, mais ou menos assim:

```
$array = [
    "codigo"    => "0123",
    "descricao" => "produto"
];
```

Mas eu precisaria que ele fosse **global**, mas tenho muitas duvidas, isto pode ser muito pesado no servidor? Variáveis globais dão conflitos entre os clientes, ou são como sessões, e não são compartilhadas entre os acessos?

E também gostaria de pedir um exemplo de como usar arrays globais.

Obrigado desde já

Comment: vc definir ele em um arquivo especifico e fazer um include nos demais arquivos que utilizam esse array.

Comment: e nesse caso ele não perderá os valores que foram inseridos por outras páginas?

Comment: Os valores dele podem mudar? se sim parece melhor usar sessão.

Comment: Sim eles podem mudar, Sessões não ficariam muito pesadas??

Answer (score 1):

Vai pesar e tem perigo até de derrubar seu server (já cometi este erro).
Crie um cookie com os dados e utilize o cookie quando precisar, ou grave em um banco de dados.
Sessão e variáveis globais servem para facilitar manutenção e armazenar variáveis de configuração, então utilize apenas quando for realmente necessário.

Comment: Entendi, acho melhor procurar por tabelas temporárias no MySQL então, acredito que cookies sejam muito perigosos, acho meio fácil de serem apagados

Comment: Faz assim, cria uma tabela no ,mysql com os dados que você precisa, e uma coluna de data de criação, mais uma coluna com o id da sessão. Depois faz uma rotina de exclusão de dados pela data, e o id da sessão vai dar segurança que os dados estão certos.

Comment: No meu caso, eu tenho algumas tabelas que são filhos de uma outra, e elas são incluidas durante o preenchimento dos campos da tabela pai, e como não posso inclui-las no db antes de incluir o pai, estou tendo essas dificuldades rsrs, e queria evitar de criar tantas tabelas, ja que só neste caso eu tenho umas 5 tabelas filhas. Mas vou estudar qual a melhor solução, e posto como uma edição aqui

Comment: Nesse caso provavelmente você tá fazendo gambiarra, tenta estudar melhor o jeito que estão sendo incluídos os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um arquivo .txt para salvar os seus dados.

```
$nome_arquivo = 'arquivo_temp_'.time().'.txt';
$_SESSION['arquivo_temp'] = $nome_arquivo;

$fp = fopen($nome_arquivo,'w+');
fwrite($fp,$dados_a_armazenar);
```

Você pode salvar os dados no arquivo .txt e depois recuperar os dados quando quiser.

```
$nome_arquivo = $_SESSION['arquivo_temp'];
$fp = fopen($nome_arquivo,'r');
```

Para excluir o arquivo você pode excluir quando o usuário sair do sistema, ou pode criar uma função que exclui os arquivos após X tempo.